# CPack: Package dependencies and Red Hat / SuSE naming schemes

Tags: cmake, package-managers, cpack, linux-distro

When using CMake / CPack to build packages, there are `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS` and `CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES` to hold a list of packages the resulting .deb / .rpm should depend on.

The distinction is helpful, as package naming shemes differ between distributions. (Example: Distros using `.deb`s add the major version of libicu to the package name -- i.e., `libicu60` -- whereas distros using `.rpm`s don't.)

However, there are differences *between `.rpm`-distros* as well, most notably between SuSE and RedHat. For example, SuSE names Boost packages `libboost_system1.56.0` etc., whereas RedHat uses `boost-system`.

Is there an ideomatic way to either

- maintain `CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES` in a distro-agnostic way, or
- detect the particular distribution / package naming pattern?

I know ways to figure out the distribution "the hard way" (parsing `uname`, checking files in `/etc` and so on) and then "hardcode" the individual package names into `CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_REQUIRES`; I was wondering if CMake / CPack offered a more idiomatic way to approach the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if CMake / CPack offered a more idiomatic way to approach the issue.

No, it doesn't. (at least yet).

The "hardcode" way is the only way nowadays. To the things that you've mentioned, I'd add running `lsb-release` if available, parse `/etc/lsb-release` and/or other distro-specific things from `/etc`...